# Odoo 8 : how to link a Many2one field automatically with the parent model?

Tags: odoo

I created a new model 'sale.order.category' in order to group Sale Order Lines in specific subcategories (allowing to display subtotals, etc.)

```
class SaleOrderCategory(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.order.category'
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
    line_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'category_id', 'Order Lines in this category')
    order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', 'Order', required=True, readonly=True)

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.order'
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    order_category_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order.category', 'order_id', 'Categories in this order', readonly=True, copy=True)
```

Just for info, here is my Order lines tree view modification to add the Category column :

```
<!-- adds a category column in the order lines list -->
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
    <field name="category_id"/>
</xpath>
```

My question is : how can I automatically populate the order_id field with the current Sales Order ID when I create a new Category through the Order Lines Tree (inside a Sales Order) ?

Many thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary remark: your use case seems related to what the official [`sale_layout`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/sale_layout) module does, so you might want to have a look at it before going any further. Perhaps you could extend it instead of starting from scratch.

Next, the most **basic answer** to your question is to pass a default value for the `order_id` field of your `sale.order.category` model when you create it from the view. You can do that by setting a `context` with an appropriate default value on the many2one field from which you will create the value:

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
    <field name="category_id" context="{'default_order_id': parent.id}"/>
</xpath>
```

Your `category_id` field is defined on the `sale.order.line` tree view, so `parent` will dynamically refer to the parent record inside the web client interface, here the `sale.order`.

However this option will not work well:

- When you're creating a new sales order, you will have to create your categories before the sales order is even saved, so there is no possible value for `order_id` yet. For this reason, you cannot make `order_id` required, and you will have to set its value again later, or you will need to save your orders before starting to add the categories.
- You already have an `order_lines` one2many field in your `sale.order.category` model. The `order_id` field is redundant with the `line_ids` field, because all lines presumably belong to the same order.

A simple **alternative** would be to entirely omit the `order_id` field (use `lines_id[0].order_id` when you need it), or to replace it with a [related field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) that will be automatically computed from the lines (it will take the value from the first order line):

```python
order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', related='line_ids.order_id', readonly=True)
```

What you should do depends on your requirements, it's difficult to say based only on your question.